# Matplotlib Horizontal Bar Plot (barh): Why are the bars on top and not beside each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to replicate [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/mastering-the-bar-plot-in-python-4c987b459053) example, except as a horizontal bar plot.

I wrote this code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import numpy as np

Fams = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9','Item10','Item11','Item12','Item13','Item14','Item15','Item16','Item17','Item18','Item19','Item20','Item21']
AllTested = [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,9,9,10,10,27]
BestSubsetTested = [1,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,1,0,1,1,2,4,1,1,8,4,9,8,11]

plt.figure(figsize=[60,40])
X = np.arange(len(Fams))
plt.barh(X,AllTested,color='g')
plt.barh(X + 0.25,BestSubsetTested,color='b')
plt.yticks([i+0.25 for i in range(len(Fams))],Fams)

# Naming the x and y axis
plt.xlabel('Tests')
plt.ylabel('Fams')

plt.savefig('day2.png',format='png')
```

When I don't add in any width parameter, the script runs, but in the output, the bars are not beside each other:

[image]

Since I want the bars to beside each other (i.e. Fam item has two bars paired together - AllTested and BestSubsetTested - , with a slightly bigger gap between each Fam item to make this clear, similar to example) , I added in 'width' parameter as in the example, but I get the error:

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_plot_species_multiple2.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.barh(X,AllTested,color='g',width=0.25)
```

Can anyone help me?

The final output should look similar to what I made except

- the bars are in pairs (i.e. item 1 has two bars, item2 has two bars)
- the name for each pair of bars should be in the middle of it
- if you could possibly show me how to tilt the name of each bar 45/make the font bigger so it's more readable that would be great because I shortened the names for this example.

Comment: `plt.barh(X + 0.25,BestSubsetTested,color='b')` bars' width/height default is `0.8`, so yes, you would see them overlap if you just offset them by `0.25`.

Comment: `plt.barh(..., height=0.4)` could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `barh`, the width of the bars is controlled by the `height` argument, not `width`. Here I set `height` to 0.4 for both `barh` calls, and offset them by +/- 0.25. You don't need to offset the yticks if you offset the bars up and down as I do here.

To rotate the tick labels, you can add `rotation=45` to the `yticks` function.

And to make the tick labels bigger, I just reduced the figure size from (60, 40) to  (12, 8). An alternative would be to change the fontsize for all the tick labels and axes labels.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import numpy as np
plt.rcdefaults()

Fams = ['Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6','Item7','Item8','Item9','Item10','Item11','Item12','Item13','Item14','Item15','Item16','Item17','Item18','Item19','Item20','Item21']
AllTested = [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,9,9,10,10,27]
BestSubsetTested = [1,0,0,0,3,0,3,0,1,0,1,1,2,4,1,1,8,4,9,8,11]

plt.figure(figsize=[12, 8])
X = np.arange(len(Fams))
plt.barh(X-0.25, AllTested,color='g', height=0.4)
plt.barh(X+0.25, BestSubsetTested,color='b', height=0.4)
plt.yticks([i for i in range(len(Fams))],Fams, rotation=45)

# Naming the x and y axis
plt.xlabel('Tests')
plt.ylabel('Fams')

plt.savefig('day2.png',format='png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a mil. Is it possible to easily add a bigger space between each item on the y axis to make it clearer? Don't worry if this is complicated it wasn't part of the original question, was just wondering if it was a quick add-on to make it more readable. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean the space between the text labels, I guess you either want to make the text smaller or change the angle of the text.

Answer (score 1):

- I recommend using pandas for dealing with tabular data
- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) makes it easy to create bar plots from multiple columns of data.

  - [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html)
- Once the data is in pandas it's also easier to analyze

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# using your data to create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'all_tested': AllTested, 'best_sub_tested': BestSubsetTested}, index=Fams)

# display(df.head())
       all_tested  best_sub_tested
Item1           3                1
Item2           3                0
Item3           3                0
Item4           3                0
Item5           4                3

# plot the dataframe
df.plot.barh(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.ylabel('Fams')
plt.xlabel('Tests')
plt.show()
```

[image]